# Current state of Stack Pointer in 8085

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, stack-pointer, 8085

In Intel 8085 microprocessor, is there any way or instruction exist for find out, to where Stack Pointer currently points to?.

Comment: You can add the SP to HL using DAD SP.

Comment: What do you mean by "find out"?

Comment: I meant getting that value to somewhere

Comment: You mean like storing it? There is an instruction for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible to find out the value of SP at any time.
Here is explanation
Using DAD Rp instruction, we can Add Rp with HL pair content. follow the steps below:

1. For our problem in hand, first we will clear HL content so that after addition of HL with SP, we will left, in HL with the content of Stack Pointer register value.

Following code will work well:

```
LXI H, 0000h; Load HL reg. pair with zero.
DAD SP ;      Adding HL and SP so that only SP value will be there in HL reg. pair.
HLT ; Once SP value is there in HL reg. pair, it can be taken any where.
```